# Variance of sum of two uniform RV

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, variance

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables, each uniformly distributed on $[-1,1],$ then find $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y).$

My attempt :
$$\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) =\operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) +2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) = 2\operatorname{Var}(X) = \frac{2}{3}.$$

But the answer given is $2;$ what am I missing?

Comment: I don't see what you've done wrong here.

Comment: I also get $2/3$. First, I calculated $E(X) = 0$ and $E(X^2) = 1/3$. Hence, $Var(X) = 1/3$. So, $Var(X+Y) = E((X+Y)^2)) = E(X^2 + 2XY + Y^2) = 2/3 + 2E(XY)$. And then I read that $E(XY) = 0$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Your answer is correct, the "given" one is wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks guys.